# Apache james STMP Flooding

Tags: apache, email, james, flooding

I want to use James as a relay to handle incoming email and put them in a system through webservice.
It works fine.
BUT I want to handle an eventual flood created by a misconfiguration of the program that sends email to this server... Is there anyway to configure a management of a temporary "banned" status for sender of this email or for destination of this email ?

Thanks

Comment: Please use the apache tag for question focussed on the HTTP server only.

Comment: Well it is NOT focus on HTTP but on mail server James, I accept STMP connection, and I want to limit it to a descent level depending on sender and / or receiver.

Comment: Sorry, I see it was @leppie who added the tag. You did fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the use of SMPT HOOK is useful here, i just wrote one

```
public class SMTPFloodProtectionHook implements RcptHook {
[...]
@Override
public HookResult doRcpt(SMTPSession session, MailAddress sender, MailAddress rcpt) {
    if (checkFloodSender(sender) || checkFloodReceiver(rcpt))
        return HookResult.deny();
    return HookResult.ok();
}
```

and modify smtpserver.conf

```
    <!-- The configuration handler chain -->
    <handlerchain>

        <handler class="org.domain.atgov.incomingevent.email.SMTPFloodProtectionHook" />
```

it denies faster than using mailet.